# How to preview video edit in faster speed?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender 3.4.1 for video editing. Typically for creative editing, I need to watch my videos (or parts of it) multiple times. It is a bit tedious that the preview plays only in "final speed" of the rendered result. It would be nice if I could tell the preview player to play the preview in e. g. 1.5x speed (while the final rendering still is 1.0x speed). Is there a setting that allows me to set the preview playback speed?

Comment: Blender is not a full feature video editor, for more editing options  I would choose software that is specialized for video editing. However, you can change the FPS setting any time you like while you're previewing, as long as you change it back to the desired speed for the final render.

Comment: The VSEQF add-on includes features for faster preview/playback modes. You can find it on GitHub.